# Mi ciclo FOR no realiza el sumatorio

Tags: bucle-for

Tengo un problema, y es que el ciclo for funciona (aparece cada cifra que itera) pero no me hace la suma de esas cifras.

Me explico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado final no debería ser 116.66666, sino el sumatorio de todas las líneas anteriores (116.6666+100+83.333...). No sé cómo hacerlo. Si alguien me ayudase, se lo agradacería mucho.

Mia

Comment: Tienes que crear un acumulador, sino solo te mostrara el ultimo resultado, a pensionContribution iniciala en 0, y dentro del for seria pensionContribution += lo demas

Comment: Bienvenida y por favor no pongas tu codigo como foto sino como texto, y especifica que lenguaje utilizas

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer sobre acumuladores en la web.

Lo que necesitas hacer es que se acumule dentro la suma de todo tu for, para eso deberías iniciar primero el acumulador en 0 y luego sumarle dentro.

```
double pensionContribution =0;
for (double i = 0; i<n ; i++){
   pensionContribution += (i/100)*(income/12);
}
```

PDTA: trata siempre de colocar código y resultado, para poder ayudarte, y estoy asumiendo que el lenguaje es java por la forma. Slds.

Comment: Un millón de gracias, me has salvado la vida. Aprendido queda!

Comment: Que bueno Mia, podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta, eso me motivaría a seguir apoyando la comunidad, muchas gracias.